# missing semicolon (;) at the end of sql statement

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

im using access database and im getting this weird error...

> missing semicolon at the end of sql statement...

p.s i try to put the semicolon but again same thing...error again... 
please help.

this is the code and the error start at Insert Into Statement  :

```
oleDbConnection1.Open();
        Int32 sasia_aktuale;
        Int32 sasia_e_shtuar = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Trim());
        string kerkesa = "select * from magazina where emri = '"+listBox1.SelectedItem+"'";
        OleDbCommand komanda = new OleDbCommand(kerkesa, oleDbConnection1);
        OleDbDataReader lexo = komanda.ExecuteReader();
        lexo.Read();
        sasia_aktuale = Convert.ToInt32(lexo.GetValue(2).ToString());
        lexo.Close();
        Int32 sasia_totale = sasia_aktuale + sasia_e_shtuar;
        oleDbDataAdapter1.InsertCommand.CommandText =
            "insert into magazina(sasia) values('" + sasia_totale + "') where emri= '" + listBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
        oleDbDataAdapter1.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Sasia per produktin " + listBox1.SelectedItem + " u shtua me sukses!", "Sasia u shtua");
        oleDbConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Please please please research "sql injection" and "parameterization"

Comment: i try... but nothing. i dont ask if i find a solution on sql documentation. this is why i ask. anyway thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing a `WHERE` clause with an `INSERT` statement, the two do not go together:

```
oleDbDataAdapter1.InsertCommand.CommandText =
        "insert into magazina(sasia) values('" + sasia_totale + "')";
```

Do you mean an `UPDATE` statement?

I'd also advise you to look up SQL injecton, and using SqlParameters to build your queries. Your code, currently is very insecure.

I can see you are after an `UPDATE` command. The `INSERT` SQL command is just going to insert whatever you give it. An example of an `UPDATE` command, using `SqlParameters` to help avoid SQL injection, is below, although this is untested as I obviously don't have access to your setup (nor am I doing this with an IDE):

```
var updateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE magazina SET sasia = @sasia_totale WHERE emri = @emri");
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sasia_totale", sasia_totale);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emri", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
oleDbDataAdapter1.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;
oleDbDataAdapter1.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: ok, thank you so much for ur answer but, i dont want to insert data without a Where clause, bcos of want to insert data in very specific field in database.
sorry for my bad english, hope u undertsand and help. thank you

Comment: Are you *updating* a row, or *inserting* **a brand new one**?

Comment: yes bro, i want to modify a specified row, but not all the row, thats why i want a Where clause to specify what row. thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you. An `UPDATE` query is what you want, after all you are *updating* a particular row *where a particular condition becomes true*.