# Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.. Access Database With C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2013

in code below i want to add multiple rows in single command in c#

but when i execute the code it throws exception with this error: Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.

I searched about this problem but this kind of problem usually happens with 
**Insert Into And where**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956396/missing-semicolon-at-the-end-of-sql-statement)

And 
I have No Idea Why this isn't work.

```
public void Main_InsertAllDatas(int currentUser, List<PasswordData> input)
    {
        // Query Execution
        // Create new command
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand Command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        // Set connection
        Command.Connection = MainConnection;

        // Query
        string strQuery = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Data] ([UserName],[Password],[Category],[Title],[Description],[UserID]) VALUES ";


        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            strQuery += "(";
            strQuery += "@iUserName" + i.ToString();
            strQuery += ",";
            strQuery += "@iPassword" + i.ToString();
            strQuery += ",";
            strQuery += "@iCategory" + i.ToString();
            strQuery += ",";
            strQuery += "@iTitle" + i.ToString();
            strQuery += ",";
            strQuery += "@iDescription" + i.ToString();
            strQuery += ",";
            strQuery += "@iUserID" + i.ToString();
            strQuery += ")";

            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iUserName" + i.ToString(), EncDecWorker.EncrypteString(input[i].Username, Key));
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iPassword" + i.ToString(), EncDecWorker.EncrypteString(input[i].Password, Key));
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iCategory" + i.ToString(), EncDecWorker.EncrypteString(input[i].Category, Key));
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iTitle" + i.ToString(), EncDecWorker.EncrypteString(input[i].Title, Key));
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iDescription" + i.ToString(), EncDecWorker.EncrypteString(input[i].Description, Key));
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iUserID" + i.ToString(), input[i].UserID);

            if (i == input.Count - 1)
            {
                break;
            }

            strQuery += ",";
        }

        strQuery += ";";

        Command.CommandText = strQuery;

        try
        {
            MainConnection.Open();
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MainConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (MainConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MainConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            MainConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

thank u for help.

Comment: What is your `strQuery` looks like when you add parameter values?

Comment: "INSERT INTO [tbl_Data] ([UserName],[Password],[Category],[Title],[Description],[UserID]) VALUES (@iUserName0,@iPassword0,@iCategory0,@iTitle0,@iDescription0,@iUserID0),(@iUserName1,@iPassword1,@iCategory1,@iTitle1,@iDescription1,@iUserID1),(@iUserName2,@iPassword2,@iCategory2,@iTitle2,@iDescription2,@iUserID2);"

Comment: i doubt ms-access supports that syntax. which version are you using?

Comment: You are adding the parentheses in the loop. That insert syntax is not even supported in MS SQL-Server < 2008, i doubt that MS Access supports it. You are also adding the same parameters again and again.

Comment: This is not good. You creating parameter part more than one time so your query will look like: `insert into (..)values(...)(...)(...)(...)`

Comment: @Reniuz whats the good way?insert them seperatly?

Comment: I have done this task before in ms sql server but in access,i got this problem

Comment: that is because ms-access does not support this syntax. check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834799%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Try for every input item generate insert statement and execute it.

Comment: so whats the best way to add multiple rows?  1.open connection 2.add 3.close 4.open 5.add 6.close etc ?

Comment: That's a bad way.why microsoft didn't let us do just like sqlserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the parentheses in the loop. That insert syntax is not even supported in MS SQL-Server < 2008, [MS Access doesn't support it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834799%28v=office.15%29.aspx) either. You are also adding the same parameters again and again, instead create the parameter once and overwrite the `Value` in the loop. Also use the `using` statement for everything that implements `IDisposable`:

```
public void Main_InsertAllDatas(int currentUser, List<PasswordData> input)
{
    string insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_Data ([UserName],[Password],[Category],[Title],[Description],[UserID]) VALUES (@UserName,@Password,@Category,@Title,@Description,@UserID)";
    using (var MainConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("..."))
    using (var Command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(insert, MainConnection))
    {
        Command.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@UserName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50));
        Command.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50));
        Command.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Category", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 100));
        Command.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Title", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 100));
        Command.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Description", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 100));
        Command.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@UserID", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer));

        MainConnection.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            Command.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = EncDecWorker.EncrypteString(input[i].Username, Key);
            // ...
            try
            {
                MainConnection.Open();
                int inserted = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } catch (Exception)
            {
                // log, show or do something else useful
                throw; // better than an empty catch
            }
        }
    } // you don't need to close the connection with using
}
```

Comment: In your code it connects to database every time and inserts a row? if the rows was too many isn't it takes so time?

Comment: Should i do this in another thread to not taking time from user?

Comment: @Adam301: there is only one connection but every row gets inserted on it's own. You need to check if it's fast enough.